# spark aggregateByKey- giving a type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Want the output like this: (167, 5). I want the sum of the ages and count

```
val people = List(("Ganga",43,'F'),("John",28,'M'),("Lolitha",33,'F'),("Don't Know",18,'T'))
val peopleRDD = sc.parallelize(people)
val kv = peopleRDD.map(x=>((x._1,x._3),x._2))
val result = kv.aggregateByKey(0,0)((x : (Int,Int) , y : Int)=> (x._1+y,x._2+1),(x:(Int,Int),y:(Int,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))
```

getting an error on the result as :

> console>:33: error: type mismatch;  found   : (Int, Int)  required:
>   Int
>
> val result = kv.aggregateByKey(0,0)((x : (Int,Int) , y : Int)=>
>   (x._1+y,x._2+1),(x:(Int,Int),y:(Int,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))

Comment: Where does `167, 5` come from? I don't get the number when I sum the age up and also the count seems to be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need additional ():

```
val result = kv.aggregateByKey((0,0))((x : (Int,Int) , y : Int)=> (x._1+y,x._2+1),(x:(Int,Int),y:(Int,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))
```

Scala REPL gets confused about parameters. You can reproduce it with simple function:

```
def func[T](arg: T)(other : (T, Int) => T) = arg
```

When you use:

```
func(0,0)((a : Int, b : Int) => a)
```

You will get the same error. What's interesting, if the second argument of `other` is for example String, everything works fine.

To avoid this compiler confusion, you should just one additional () to tell compiler that you want a tuple